# asp.net: using resource expressions with the resources in a separate project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, localization, expression

I'm pretty sure this is something super easy, but how do i access a resource that is in a separate project using the expression syntax?
I thought it would be like so:

```
<%$ Resources:SomeNamespace.Resources.Web, PleaseSelectAnImage %>
```

where SomeNamespace.Resources is the project that the resources are located in.

i normally just do `<%= SomeNamespace.Resources.Web.PleaseSelectAnImage%>`  but i need to have this inside a control.

```
 <kw:SlickUpload ID="SlickUpload1" runat="server" 
            ValidExtensions=".png, .gif, .jpg" 
            InvalidExtensionMessage="<%$ Resources:SomeNamespace.Resources.Resources.Web, PleaseSelectAnImage %>" >
```

so when i just do what i normally do, it puts 
'<%= SomeNamespace.Resources.Web.PleaseSelectAnImage%>" literally.

my project name is SomeNamespace.Resources.  the resource file name is Web.  and the key is PleaseSelectAnImage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Patricia, you'll need to implement a custom `ResourceProviderFactory` and corresponding `IResourceProvider` in order to do this. Some good reference can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Custom_Resource_Provider.aspx).